# reduceByKey processing each flatMap output without aggregating value on key in GraphX

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a problem running GraphX

```
val adjGraph= adjGraph_CC.vertices 
   .flatMap { case (id, (compID, adjSet)) => (mapMsgGen(id, compID, adjSet)) } 
      // mapMsgGen will generate a list  of msgs each msg has the form K->V

   .reduceByKey((fst, snd) =>mapMsgMerg(fst, snd)).collect   
      // mapMsgMerg will merge each two msgs  passed to it
```

what I was expecting reduceByKey to do is to group the whole output of flatMap by the key (K) and process the list of values (Vs) for each Key (K) using the function provided.

what is happening is the each output of flatMap (using the function mapMsgGen)  which is a list of K->V pairs (not the same K usually) is processed immediately using reduceByKey function mapMsgMerg and before the whole flatMap finish.

need some clarification please 
I don't undestand what is going wrong or is it that I understand flatMap and reduceByKey wrong??

Regards,

Maher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to produce the entire output of `flatMap` before starting `reduceByKey`. In fact, if you're not using the intermediate output of `flatMap` it's better not to produce it and possibly save some memory.

If your `flatMap` outputs a list that contains `'k' -> v1` and `'k' -> v2` there's no reason to wait until the entire list has been produced to pass `v1` and `v2` to `mapMsgMerge`. As soon as those two tuples are output `v1` and `v2` can be combined as `mapMsgMerge(v1, v2)` and `v1` and `v2` discarded if the intermediate list isn't used.

I don't know the details of the Spark scheduler well enough to say if this is guaranteed behavior but it does seem like an instance of what [the original paper](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~matei/papers/2012/nsdi_spark.pdf) calls 'pipelining' of operations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer it is more clear now,so what is really happening is that reduceByKey function (which is mapMsgMerg) is applied  as soon as there are two outputs for function in the flatMap (which is mapMsgGen).